# mcrypt characters

Tags: php, database, phpmyadmin, mcrypt

I am currently trying to teach myself mcrypt in PHP.  I just copied and pasted the following sample code into my php web page:

```
$size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_CFB);
$iv = mcrypt_create_iv($size, MCRYPT_DEV_RANDOM);

echo $iv;
```

The following code produced this:

```
öÈÅê^ƒ€™Ç8xîÉ/...
```

Is this a good solution for producing password salts?  If so, I have a small concern for the foreign looking character this method produces.  I plan on storing this in a Database & would like to know if the characters produced here should influence my decision on collation?  So far, I've been using `utf_encoding_ci` for collation.  I don't know much about collation or how to treat different characters in a database.

Comment: That's *binary* data and should be treated as such. It doesn't have an "encoding" because it doesn't represent text. See [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/).

Comment: The foreign looking characters exist because the IV isn't meant to be a string in the literal sense.  It's a binary production of bytes that is random and so will not form words or even letters most of the time.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know anything about collation or anything, but if you are encrypting passwords in a database, some of the recommended methods to use are [`md5()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.md5.php) and [`sha1()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sha1.php) for encryption. They should be fine for normal use. The explanations in the comments are good explanations of why there are strange characters and how to store them in a database.